# Is it possible to get the release version in Heroku using PHP?

Tags: heroku

I'd like to get the release version of my app in Heroku on PHP. I was hoping it might be available as an environment variable, for example like `$_ENV['HEROKU_RELEASE']` might retrieve `v23`. Is there a way to get ahold of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is possible, by enabling [dyno metadata](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata) on your app with the following command:

> heroku labs:enable runtime-dyno-metadata -a

Then, Heroku will set a `HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION` environment variable on your app (as well as other ones, which are all described in the article linked above).

That variable includes the number of the current release for your app.